# Recursive fibonacci using Big Integer time complexity

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, fibonacci

Could you please explain the complexity of the following algorithm?

```java
public BigInteger fibBigInt() {
    return fibBigInt( 
               BigInteger.valueOf(n), 
               ONE, 
               BigInteger.valueOf(0));
}

private BigInteger fibBigInt(BigInteger start, BigInteger val, BigInteger previous) {
    if (start.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 0) {
        return previous;
    }
    return fibBigInt( 
               start.subtract(ONE),  
               val.add(previous), 
               val);
}
```

How does this recursion run in O(n) time? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What time do you think it runs in? Do you have some estimate/reasoning?

Comment: @dratenik IDK. I'm having a hard time understanding this recursion. The ones I read about involve the typical O(2^n) time. But this seems like tail recursion so I haphazardly guessed its time to be O(n).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fibonacci is the standard example of different complexity classes since the naive approach as by definition takes `O(2^n)` time, where as there is a linear solution which takes only `O(n)` time. This one works with the linear pattern.

The idea is to have a starting value (`fib(0)` and `fib(1)`) and iteratively compute `fib(n+2)` from `fib(n+1)` by calling it a single time. The trick is to store not only the result from `fib(n+1)` but from `fib(n)` as well. This is done by "rotating" the values for `fib(n+1)` and `fib(n)` in each recursion step.

So explaining how this works is best with an example (`n`=5). Please note that the  argument `m` is the input value which fibonacci number you want. `m` is decreasing in value and the value 0 marks the end for the recursion. Your code snipped runs with the counter `m` and has no attribute `n`.

| `n` | `m` | `fib(n+1)` | `fib(n)` | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 1 | 0 | first 6 lines of your code |
| 1 | 4 | 1+0 = 1 | 1 | iteration step, last 4 lines of your code. The current `fib(n+1)` is the `fib(n+1)`+`fib(n)` from the line above, `fib(n)` is the `fib(n+1)` from the line above. |
| 2 | 3 | 1+1 = 2 | 1 | see above |
| 3 | 2 | 2+1 = 3 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 3+2 = 5 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 0 | 5+3 = 8 | 5 | now the term `start.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0))` becomes 0 and therefore the value for `fib(n)` (5) will be returned and "forwarded" back through each recursive call. |

This approach is clearly linear and runs therefore in `O(n)`.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I am now starting to understand how it runs linear time. 

So the recurrence relation for this specific method is T(n-1) +O(1)?

Comment: no, it is T(n)=T(n-1)+c where c is the time consumption for the constant time amount of comparing, adding, forwarding and so on. This adds up to T(n)=T(n-1)+c = n*c + constant time for recursion end;  therefore T(n) is in O(n)

Comment: Wait, why is T(n) = T(n-1)+c = n*c?

Comment: ^^ T(0) = c'; T(n) = T(n-1)+c = T(n-2) + c + c  = T(n-2) + 2c = T(n-3) + 3c = ... = T(1) + (n-1)\*c = T(0) + n\*c = c' +n\*c